# How to sort/order data from multiple models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am trying to generate a report that lists the most recent revenue changes. I am trying to determine the best way to sort (payments, refunds, fee charges, and credits) the most recent changes, paginate them, and display them to the user.

These items are in 4 different and unrelated models (Payment, Refund, FeeCharge, and Credit). Is there a way to query this from the database?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the relationship between each model?

Comment: Also, do you want to have a list of most recently changed records that are either `Payment`, `Refund`, `FeeCharge` or `Credit`? or one list for each type?

Comment: this is easy with STI (single table inheritance)

Comment: There are no relationships between the models. And i would like to have one list containing either paymenst, refunds, fee charges, or credits. @MrYoshiji

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to implement this with Rails. Eventually, an STI is an option but inheritance is not always the way to go (see inheritance vs composition).

One way to see this is that all 4 different models share the same *concern*: they should be retrievable based on some field (in your case, using the `updated_at`).

With this in mind, you can create a SQL view to encapsulate this concern.  This view will do a `UNION` between each table and expose fields. Then, you can create a Rails read-only model to represent a row from this view and simply query via ActiveRecord.

Let me know if this option is interesting for you and if you need a concrete example.